# Can a "Lightning App Builder" page be used for the "New" action?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have a "Lightning App Builder" "Record Page" that I've used "Assign as App Default" to make it the page that opens when a specific object type is viewed.

I would like to route to the same page when the "New" action is used but see no way to do that. Is there a way?

(In the object's "Buttons, Links and Actions", I do see separate "Lightning Experience Override" settings for New, Edit, View but these only allow the selection of a "Lightning Component" not a "Lightning App Builder" page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and doubtful it would ever be this way, because App Builder record pages are all built around the idea that the data is already there and cannot auto-adapt to the scenario of creating a new record.

Comment: So is a work-around perhaps to add lightning:actionOverride Lightning Component for "New" that inserts a record and then routes somehow to the record page?

Comment: I suppose you could do that? But it breaks the normal behaviour that "New" does not cause a DML insert until you click Save. There are a lot of standard elements that are inapplicable to a "New" scenario like related lists. Perhaps it is better to put an actual create UI (maybe using the new `Lightning:recordEdit` Base Components that simplify it, or Lightning Data Service) in your "New" override, and include only the items from the record page that make sense to have on a "New" form.

Comment: For my situation - something like the start of a flow interview - I've gone with a create of the record then a "e.force:navigateToSObject" done from a "lightning:actionOverride,force:hasSObjectName" component. Thanks for your comments.